# Connect EF Core to Azure Databricks

Tags: entity-framework-core, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to find out if it is possible to use EF Core (5) to query an Azure Databricks DB. Unfortunately I'm finding nearly no information about it at all.
Does anybody know of a database provider capable to do that? Or is this possible with a common built in provider?
I found an article showing how to access Spark data with EF6 using System.Data.CData.SparkSQL, but that doesn't seem to be exactly what I was looking for. :(
Thank you,
cyberblast

Comment: look if it's possible to use ODBC or JDBC from EF. If yes, you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/integrations/bi/jdbc-odbc-bi

Comment: I means new EF Core provider needed. Not trivial task.